# default behavior in an application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have index.aspx , index.html and another mvc application. I found mvc application takes the priority to execute. I want to know how to determine the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS you can specify the order of default documents:

[image]

Also you might want to exclude those documents from your MVC application routes so that they are directly served by IIS:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("default.htm");
```

Comment: thanks, however I want to know why MVC application has higher priority than default document?

Comment: This was not the case for IIS 6 unless you were using a wildcard mapping but starting from IIS7 if you are running in integrated mode all requests are processed by the managed pipeline and so they first hit the MVC application.